# Is it possible to use doReturn() and CALLS_REAL_METHODS with mockito-kotlin?

Tags: mockito, kotlin

My understanding is that to use `doReturn()` with [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) is that I must call it from within a

```
val mockObj = mock<TheClass> {
    on { method } doReturn something
}
```

how can I specify that this must use `CALLS_REAL_METHODS` ?

or can I use `doReturn()` in some other way with `val mockObj : TheClass = mock(Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)` instead?

*just to clarify - this is a `doReturn()` (not `when/whenever`) question*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Mockito-Kotlin 1.2.0 `mock()` takes optional parameters:

```
val mockObj : TheClass = mock(defaultAnswer = Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
```

You can use the stubbing mechanism to then again override this default behavior for individual methods:

```
val mockObj = mock<TheClass>(defaultAnswer = Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS) {
  on { method() } doReturn something
}
```

Comment: ah, I see the key is to use `defaultAnswer=`. thanks